# Kendo UI combo box breaking knockout binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, kendo-ui

I have the following line of HTML that works fine.

```
<select style="margin-left: 20px" id="agencies" data-bind="options:agencies, value: selectedAgency, optionsText:'name'"> </select>
```

When I enable the Kendo UI combo box like this, I lose all entries in the combo box:

```
  $("#agencies").kendoComboBox();
```

Anyone know how I can fix this?

TIA.

Answer (score 2):

Check [this library](http://rniemeyer.github.com/knockout-kendo/) by Ryan Niemeyer which provides Knockout.js bindings for Kendo UI widgets.